# Animate + onpointermove keeps resetting in Safari

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a website, where I have a "flash light" effect where a `div` follows my mouse (Like https://www.poppr.be/en). I'm following thise CodePen https://codepen.io/Hyperplexed/full/KKBjvbG

It works fine in Chrome, however in Safari the animation where the `div` follows the mouse only happens when the mouse is still. Otherwise it seems to keep resetting to the default position until the mouse is still (the CodePen also does this)

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the CodePen uses animate, which acts differently in Safari. Switching to use `.style` adds consistent effect across Chrome and Safari.

From:

```js
const blob = document.getElementById("blob");

window.onpointermove = event => { 
  const { clientX, clientY } = event;
  
  blob.animate({
    left: `${clientX}px`,
    top: `${clientY}px`
  }, { duration: 3000, fill: "forwards" });
}
```

To:

```
  const blob = document.getElementById("blob");

  window.onpointermove = (event) => {
    const { clientX, clientY } = event;

    // Add a delay of 100ms before moving the blob
    blob.style.left = `${clientX}px`;
    blob.style.top = `${clientY}px`;
  };

  // Add CSS transition to create smooth animation
  blob.style.transition = "all 0.6s ease-out";
```